# Override NGRX Store selector in test seems to get ingored

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, ngrx

Overriding the selector whilst returning `null` still returns the data as returned by the override defined at initialization. Also tried `setState` but didnt work either.

Trying to test the `else` in this:

```
this.store.pipe(select(singleUserSelector, { _id: this.userModel?._id })).subscribe((state: IUserSelected) => {
  console.log('singleUserSelector', this.userModel?._id, state);
  if (state) {
    this.componentState = state.componentState;
    this.userModel = state.userModel;
    this.selected = true;
  } else if (this.selected) {
    this.componentState = ComponentState.VIEW;
    this.selected = false;
  }
});
```

Test

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
      providers: [provideMockStore(
        {
          initialState,
          selectors: [
            { selector: usersSelector, value: users },
            { selector: singleUserSelector, value: { componentState: ComponentState.VIEW, userModel: userIndy } },
            { selector: mainComponentStateSelector, value: ComponentState.VIEW }]
        }
      )],
      declarations: [UserComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should have not selected state based on singleUserSelector not returning valid user', () => {
    const mockedStateFocusedSelectorNull = store.overrideSelector(singleUserSelector, null);
    // setState doesnt work either
    // store.setState({ userFocused: null } as ApplicationState);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.selected).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.componentState).toBe(ComponentState.VIEW);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick, obviously..

```
const mockedStateFocusedSelectorNull = store.overrideSelector(singleUserSelector, null);
store.refreshState(); // <------
```